# Tmux key bindings not working

Tags: linux, macos, mac, osx-lion, tmux

I installed tmux using homebrew on Mac OSX Lion a while back.  Suddenly the keybindings have stopped working.  For example if I try Ctrl-b then c (Create new window) it just types c in the terminal window.  How can I fix this and make tmux useable again?

Comment: have you changed  your .tmuxconf file? Are you using the default terminal or iterm2. iterm2 has buil in tmux integration now.

Comment: I have not changed .tmuxconf, and tmux does not work in the default terminal or iterm2

Comment: Also when I ssh into another computer from my Mac, and use tmux, the keybindings work fine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting my `~/.tmux.conf` and using `tmux kill-server`

Comment: tmux kill-server worked for me.  I didn't need to delete ~/.tmux.conf.

Comment: To anyone reading this - kill-server *kills your tmux session*. Part of me knew that, but not the same part that copy pasted tmux kill-server hoping it'd fix my issues. Try the other fix first.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your situation, "kill-server" might be overkill.

For me, the non working keys is fixed by just detaching the client that stopped working, and re attaching to it; in a different terminal:

```
tmux detach-client -s mysession
tmux attach-session -t mysession
```

Answer (score 0):

When I restarted my computer, a typo in one particular command in tmux.conf didn't let it run. I fixed it and in the tmux session itself reloaded it using `source ~/.tmux.conf` and bindings started working again.