# Faile to switch between two latest windows in tmux on Ubuntu 16.04 with default command C-b l?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

The default command `C-b l` to switch between two latest windows doesn't work on my Ubuntu 16.04.
But it works if set `bind-key l last-window` after started tmux server.

I tried to set the bind key command in ~/.tmux.conf:
`bind-key l last-window` or `bind-key a last-window`

`C-b l` still doesn't work, but `C-b a` works.

Why `C-b l` doesn't work? How to trace the issue?

Reference:

[How to switch between two latest windows in tmux?](https://superuser.com/questions/429558/how-to-switch-between-two-latest-windows-in-tmux)

[Ubuntu tmux manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/tmux.1.html)

Comment: It works for me in Kubuntu 16.04 (I use F1 instead of C-b).

Comment: @Gribouillis, Thanks for your comments. I tried with F1 as the prefix key, it is the same for Ubuntu 16.04. `F1 l` doesn't work, but `F1 a` works. I want to keep the default prefix key. So any idea?

Comment: Did you check by typing `C-b :` to enter command mode, then `list-keys` ?

Comment: @Gribouillis, yes, I checked with list-keys, only  `bind-key    -T prefix a                last-window`  is display, but defalut `prefix l` is not

Comment: Try perhaps `bind-key 'l' last-window` (with quotes)

Comment: `bind-key 'l' last-window` (with quotes) doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/406421/tmux-key-bindings-not-working) ?

Comment: @Gribouillis, thank you very much. After removed the .tmux.conf, `C-b l` works. 
Then I tried with `tmux list-keys | grep "prefix l"` to find the bind key.
It shows that `bind-key l select-pane -R` overwrite the default behavior.

Thank you again. How can I close the question or make your comments as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `~/.tmux.conf` as in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/406421/tmux-key-bindings-not-working).

List my steps:
1. find the bind key with `tmux list-keys | grep "prefix l"`
2. If exists with another command, remove it from .tmux.conf and restart your tmux;
if it does not exist, your setting for bind key is not effective.

Comment: I edited the answer and list my steps here. I didn't use `tmux kill-server`

Comment: @user1086907 Now I don't understand the second step. In your case, what was the result of `tmux list-keys | grep "prefix l"` ? Also you removed the `~/.tmux.conf` didn't you?

Comment: I restore the `~/.tmux.conf` after found that the issue caused by it, then `tmux list-keys | grep "prefix l"`, and found that the shortcut is bound for another command.